# Writing down gerbes explicitly over the projective line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, stacks, gerbes

Let $X = [\mathbb P^1/(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)]$, where we take the trivial action of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb P^1$. Is this DM stack over $\mathbb C$  a gerbe over $\mathbb P^1$? Is it the non-trivial element of $H^2(\mathbb P^1,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$?

If not, what does the non-trivial element of $H^2(\mathbb P^1,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$? then "look" like?

Comment: Well, you took the trivial action, so $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times B \mathbb{Z}_2$, and with the obvious projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$ this is the trivial $B \mathbb{Z}_2$-torsor over $\mathbb{P}^1$ and hence it represents the trivial element of $H^2$. You want to write down the nontrivial $B \mathbb{Z}_2$-torsor.

Comment: Try the gerbe of square roots of $\mathscr{O}(1)$.

Comment: Btw what about the action $[x_0:x_1]\mapsto[x_0:(-x_1)]=[(-x_0):x_1]$?